# Let $f$ be analytic function defined on the open unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$. Then which are of the following true?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic function defined on the open unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$. Then $f$ is constant if

$1.~~f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=0$ for all $n\geq1.$
$ 2. ~~f(z)=0$ for all $|z|=1/2$
$ 3. ~~f\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=0$ for all $n\geq1.$
$ 4. ~~f(z)=0$ for all $z\in (-1,1)$

I used Identity theorem and conclude that $1$, $3$ and $4$ are true. But I am confused with $2$. Please help me with some hints or ideas.

Comment: If $A$ is a set with a limit point in the open unit disk and $f(z) = 0$ for all $z\in A$, then $f=0$ on the open unit disk. Hence $f$ is constant if any of 1-4 are true.

Comment: Sir can you please give me a reference to that? or explain a bit more @copper.hat

Comment: Try Theorem 10.18 in Rudin's "Real & Complex analysis". I would guess that most complex analysis texts will have a version of this, it follows almost directly from the power series representation.

Comment: OK thank you @copper.hat

Comment: Every point on $\{z \in \mathbb{C} ; |z| = \dfrac{1}{2} \}$ is a limit point. As every neighborhood around everypoint of the set contains the points of the set. Is it ?

Comment: How do you argue about 1 and 3?

Answer (score 2):

(Since I am going to answer an old unanswered question, here I am going to discuss all options)

**Answer:** Here all the four options are correct.

**Discussion:** Here $~f~$ be analytic defined on the open disc in $\mathbb C$. 
In option $(1)$ and $(3)$, we see that 
$f\left(\dfrac 1n\right)=0~,$ and $~f\left(\dfrac 1{n^2}\right)=0~$ for all $~n\ge 1~.$
$\implies~f~$ has zeros at the points $~z=1/n~$ and $~z=1/{n^2}~.$
Also, the limit points of zeros of $~f~$ is zero and the function is analytic at zero.
Then, by Identity theorem, the function is identically zero.
Thus $~f~$ is a constant.
So options $(1)$ and $(3)$ are correct.

In general, zeros of a non-constant analytic function are isolated, but in the options $(2)$ and $(4)$, zeros of analytic function are non-isolated. It implies that $~f~$ is constant. 
So options $(2)$ and $(4)$ are correct.

Comment: Very nice!${}{}{}{}{}{}$